# Batch import SVGs as Drawables in AndroidStudio 3.6 (How?)

Tags: android-studio, svg, android-drawable, android-studio-3.6

I have quite a few (208 currently) SVG files that I programmatically turn into `.imageset` assets for my iOS app. I'd like to do the same for Android somehow.

I'm pretty pleased with the result I get by using `New>>Vector Asset` from the Studio menu. But I really don't want to do that 208 times. And more times in the future when the SVGs get updated.

Is there a way I can somehow script this import process?

I don't want to batch process them on some website somewhere. And I'd like to use the current studio tools if possible somehow. Or a completely independent command line tool.

Answer (score 82):

The Resource Manager tool that was added in Android Studio version 3.4 can bulk import SVGs and convert them into vector drawables.

1. `Tools` → `Resource Manager`
2. Select the `Drawable` tab
3. Click the `+` button in the top left corner
4. Select `Import Drawables`

There you can select all the files you want to import at once.
More details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager).

Comment: Definitely should be top answer! Integrated directly into Android Studio without using any third-party tool. Thank you!

Comment: The more I use Android Studio, the more I learn a lot of my old 3rd-party tools are now baked in.

Answer (score 1):

You can download this jar file: [Svg2VectorAndroid-1.0.1.jar](https://github.com/ravibhojwani86/Svg2VectorAndroid/blob/master/Svg2VectorAndroid-1.0.1.jar)

Just run this command:

```
java -jar C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Svg2VectorAndroid-1.0.1.jar C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\your_svg_folder
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Is there any reason this isn't an open source project somehwere? Or maybe it is? It's working, but I'm not a big fan of random binaries from the internet...

Comment: For any others that stumble on this, one thing I've found is that it's important that your drawable filenames end up as lower_case_under_score_names. AndroidStudio will complain about weird things if they are not in that format.

Comment: I'm finding that while this converts some images, a lot of images are not converted correctly. Parts are left out. No error message is given that even tells that there were problems, visual inspection alone is the only way to detect the omissions. Some of these failed conversions import fine with the interactive `New>>Vector Asset` approach, so I think this library is not as good as the current one, even though it can do batch processing.

Comment: @TravisGriggs it is an open source project, you just gotta truncate the URL to get to the github repo https://github.com/ravibhojwani86/Svg2VectorAndroid

Answer (score -2):

Add these to your gradle file

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'}
```